# How to force Hot Chocolate Graphql to use left join on null Id to stop under fetching?

Tags: c#, graphql, entity-framework-core, hotchocolate

I have an issue where the Sql generated from a Graphql request is using an inner join that is causing data to be skipped. This is because the join is happening on an id field that can be null. I have no control over the id field so I cannot just make the field not-null. I have re-written the Sql exchanging the inner join for a left join and it works as desired but I cannot figure out how to get Hot Chocolate to do the same.

Example of relationship (not actual code being worked with):

```
public class Person {
  public Guid PersonId {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public Guid CarId {get;set;}
  public virtual Car OwnedCar {get;set}
}

public class Car {
  public Guid CarId {get;set;}
  public string Brand {get;get;}
  public virtual ICollection<Person> OwnersOfThisTypeOfCar {get;set;}
}
```

At the database context I have a many to one relationship set up like

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
//code omitted for brevity
modelBuilder.Entity<Car>(entity => {
  //code omitted for brevity
  entity.HasMany(d => d.OwnersOfThisTypeOfCar)
       .WithOne(p => p.OwnedCar)
       .HasForeignKey(p => p.CarId);

});
```

when making a Graphql request like:

```
{person() {name, ownedCar{ brand }}}
```

I expect to get back all people in the DB and the car they own or null for the car if they don't have one. So I expect the Sql generated to look like

```
Select t.name, t1.brand from people as t 
left join cars as t1 on t.carId = t1.carId;
```

Instead I get

```
Select t.name, t1.brand from people as t 
inner join cars as t1 on t.carId = t1.carId;
```

which, of course only returns the people that have cars.

I feel that there is some simple solution that would allow Hot Chocolate to specify that the field / type only be populated when it is not null (thereby informing EfCore to use a left join) but I just can't find it. Any help in this would be greatly appreciated as I have spent quite a few hours trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that runs into this the solution is to add an .IsRequired(false); to the end of your entity builder so:

```
  entity.HasMany(d => d.OwnersOfThisTypeOfCar)
   .WithOne(p => p.OwnedCar)
   .HasForeignKey(p => p.CarId)
   .IsRequired(false);
```